# Help with HQL: Aggregate (count)

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Given the model Activity containing a bag with models of type Report (one to many). I would like to get a list of all activities, containing the number of reports of each activity. This two queries don't lead to any good, the counter is always 1 (which is wrong):

```
select act, (select count(r) from act.Reports r) from Activity act
```

Or:

```
select act, count( elements(act.Reports) ) from Activity act group by act.ActivityId, act.Title
```

Is it possible to write a proper query in HQL to solve this easy task?

Thx for any tipps!
sl3dg3

Edit:
Following the mappings. Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class
        name="Core.Models.Config.Activity, Core"
        table="Activity"
    >

        <!-- primary key -->
        <id name="ActivityId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="property">
            <column name="ActivityId" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <!-- Properties -->
        <many-to-one name="Title" fetch="join" cascade="all"/>

        <!-- One-To-Many Reports -->
        <bag name="Reports" inverse="true" fetch="join">
            <key column="ReportId" />
            <one-to-many class="Core.Models.Report"/>
        </bag>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapping Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class
        name="Core.Models.Report, Core"
        table="Report"
    >

    <!-- primary key -->
    <id name="ReportId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="property">
        <column name="ReportId" not-null="true"/>
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <!-- Properties (shortened - there are more many-to-one and one bag -->
    <property name="Created" />
    <many-to-one name="Activity" column="ActivityId" />

</class>
```

Class Activity:

```
public class Activity
{

    public Activity()
    {
        Title = new Translation();
    }

    public virtual int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Translation Title { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Class Report:

```
public class Report
{

    /// <summary>
    /// HNIBERNATE ONLY
    /// </summary>
    public Report() 
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Init Report
    /// </summary>
    public Report(User author)
    {
        // ... Shortened
        Activity = new Activity();
    }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first HQL query has the wrong syntax. Try this instead:

```
select act, (select count(*) from act.Reports) from Activity act
```

Your second HQL query cannot work, because you would need all the columns in the GROUP BY clause. Try this instead:

```
select act.ActivityId, act.Title, count( elements(act.Reports) ) 
from Activity act 
group by act.ActivityId, act.Title
```

**Edit:**

Ah, I think this might be the bug:

```
<bag name="Reports" inverse="true" fetch="join">
    <key column="ActivityId" /> <-- instead of ReportId
    <one-to-many class="Core.Models.Report"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: As for the first query: Unfortunately I still get for each Activity one (and only one) Report as count. As for the second query, that's exactly what I wrote above - mine was correct too, but not as nicely formatted ;-)

Comment: @sl3dg3 Sorry, I did not test these properly. I just tested the queries in a test environment and they worked fine. Could you perhaps post the mappings and class definitions?

Comment: @sl3dg3 They look ok. Have you checked the SQL that is generated? What happens if you run those against the DB directly?

Comment: The query in SQL results in `select activity0_.ActivityId as col_0_0_, 
 (select count(*) from Report reports1_ where activity0_.ActivityId=reports1_.ReportId) as col_1_0_, 
 activity0_.ActivityId as ActivityId12_, activity0_.Title as Title12_ 
from Activity activity0_` which seems to be incorrect...

Comment: @sl3dg3 Ok, I think I found it. See my Edit.

Comment: @ Florion: Ah... you are absolutely right, that was silly :-/  ... now it works as expected! Thank you for your patience and time!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is something like this in **SQL**:

```
select 
  act.*, 
 (select count(*) from Reports rep where rep.id = act.reportId)
from Activity act
```

It would be easiest using `size()`, but unfortunately this is **not working**:

```
select act, size(act.Reports)
from Activity act
```

According to the docs, `size` is not available in the select clause. Interestingly, **it actually works** with `.size`, but not with `size()`, which should actually be equivalent:

```
select act, act.Reports.size
from Activity act
```

It may be worth a feature request to also make the function syntax (`size()`) working.

The officially working **group by syntax** is cumbersome, because you need to group by all mapped Activity properties:

```
select act, count(*)
from Activity act left join act.Reports rep
group by act.id, act.Name, act.Whatever
```

So I tried finally this variant and it seems to be **exactly what you need**:

```
select act, (select count(*) from act.Reports)
from Activity act
```

Comment: Tested that, but the generated SQL (`select activity0_.ActivityId as col_0_0_, 
 count(reports1_.ReportId) as col_1_0_, activity0_.ActivityId as ActivityId12_, activity0_.Title as Title12_ 
 from Activity activity0_, Report reports1_ 
 where activity0_.ActivityId=reports1_.ReportId`) fails saying: `Column 'Activity.ActivityId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Thx - as it turned out I had a mapping - error (see above). So far you have came up with the same solution :-)